# Pyspark higher order functions - sum 2 values in array of structs at once?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe where one column is an array of structs.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, [{"col1": 10, "col2": 0.8, "col3": 0.1}, {"col1": 9, "col2": 1.8, "col3":0.0}, {"col1": 8, "col2": 1.9, "col3": None}])], ['rowNum', 'vals'])
```

I am trying to create an aggregate function that sums all of the col2s and divides it by all of the col1s you can ignore col3. I know how to create an aggregate function if I was just summing one of the columns (using higher order functions in pyspark 2.4+), but is it possible to sum 2 items at the same time, or do I have to do it as 2 separate steps.

If I have to do it as 2 separate steps, then I can do:

```
df = df.withColumn("sum", F.aggregate("vals", F.lit(0.0), lambda x, y: x + y.col2)) \
.withColumn("denom", F.aggregate("vals", F.lit(0.0), lambda x, y: x + y.col1)) \
.withColumn("output", F.col('sum')/F.col('denom'))
```

I was wondering if there is a higher order function that does this in a cleaner way/in 1 step? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of two elements to aggregate `sum` and `denom`. Also, *AGGREGATE* or *REDUCE* have this signature: `reduce(array<T>, B, function<B, T, B>, function<B, R>): R` where `function<B, R>` you can apply another function over your aggregation and it's exactly what I do at the end to divide sum by denom.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, [
  {"col1": 10.0, "col2": 0.8, "col3": 0.1}, 
  {"col1": 9.0, "col2": 1.8, "col3":0.0}, 
  {"col1": 8.0, "col2": 1.9, "col3": None}])], schema='rowNum int, vals array<struct<`col1`:double, `col2`:double, `col3`:double>>')

expr = ('AGGREGATE(vals, ARRAY(CAST(0.0 AS DOUBLE), CAST(0.0 AS DOUBLE)), (acc, el) -> '
        'ARRAY(acc[0] + el.col2, acc[1] + el.col1), acc -> acc[0] / acc[1])')
df.withColumn('output', F.expr(expr)).show()

+------+--------------------+-------------------+
|rowNum|                vals|             output|
+------+--------------------+-------------------+
|     1|[{10.0, 0.8, 0.1}...|0.16666666666666666|
+------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks! what if the length of the array of structs is not limited to 3, would this method work for an array without a fixed length?

Comment: Yes, you can have `n` elements in your array. Higher-order functions were made to handle arrays with dynamical sizes without hardcoding it

Comment: Yes, I am testing it out now. If I wanted to make the col1 (col2) a dynamic name would that be possible? For ex: instead of el.col2, make it el.{0} and then do a .format( and pass it in in the expression

Comment: Nevermind - was able to figure this out ^! looks good, many thanks!